# How I can use useState hook in an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm beginner in React and I want create a component that is in constant motion, incrementing its style property `transform:translate`, but the increment isn't what I expected. What's happening?

This is my code:

```
function Point() {

  const [countX, setCountX] = useState(0);
  const [countY, setCountY] = useState(0);

  setInterval(() => {
    setCountX((count) => count + 1);
    setCountY((count) => count + 1);

    console.log(countX+":"+countY);

  }, 500);

  const styles = {
    transform: `translate(${countX}px,${countY}px)`,
  };

  return <PointStyle style={styles} />;
}
```

And the output in the console from `console.log(countX+":"+countY)` is as follows:

0:0 
1:1 
0:0 
2:2 
1:1 
4:4 
0:0 
5:5 
2:2 
7:7 
1:1 
9:9 
4:4 
10:10 
11:11 
0:0 
12:12 
5:5 
14:14 
2:2 
7:7

Comment: What is your required output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call one of your setState functions (`setCountX`, or `setCountY`) the component will end up being rerendered. This will cause the `setInterval` to be called repeatedly creating many intervals running out of sync all attempting to update the X and Y position of your point.

To fix this you need to put your `setInterval` code inside of a `useEffect`.

```
const Point = () => {

    const [countX, setCountX] = useState(0);
    const [countY, setCountY] = useState(0);

    // The below useEffect will be triggered on component mount and 
    // whenever a value in the dependency array changes (an empty 
    // dependency array is only on mount, such as this example).
    // 
    // The function returned from the useEffect is a clean up function
    // that will be run whenever a value in the dependency array changes
    // or when the component unmounts
    useEffect(() => {
        // Create interval to change point X and Y, ensuring to store
        // the returned ID so that the interval can be cleared later.
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            setCountX((count) => count + 1);
            setCountY((count) => count + 1);

            console.log(countX + ":" + countY);

        }, 500);

        // clean up function created in the current closure will
        // keep hold of previously stored intervalId value.
        return () => {
            // Clear interval (in this example only run on component unmount)
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, [] /* Dependency Array */)

    const styles = {
        transform: `translate(${countX}px,${countY}px)`,
    };

    return <PointStyle style={styles} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time your component re-renders, it is creating an interval. Also, the previous intervals are not getting cleaned up. So, all your intervals are updating the count at the same time.

You need to move the `setInterval` into a `useEffect` and also cleanup the interval.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setCountX((count) => count + 1);
    setCountY((count) => count + 1);

    console.log(countX+":"+countY);

  }, 500);
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [])
```